# Не могу добавить сайт в IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, iis

Пытался развернуть сайт на ASP.NET в IIS. Выдавало ошибку. Начал копаться и устанавливать недостающие компоненты. Теперь даже просто сайт добавить не могу. Как это можно исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Компоненты Windows
[image: Компоненты Windows]

Comment: тип привязки-то выберите...

Comment: Нельзя. Там пусто

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему достаточно банально и просто. Отключил службы IIS в компонентах Windows, перезагрузил компьютер и включил их обратно